# Better way to get certain fields from a SQLAlchemy KeyedTuple

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a [SQLAlchemy KeyedTuple](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.util.KeyedTuple) with several fields. I would like to get a tuple (or, if possible, a KeyedTuple) with all its fields except for two of them, which I know by name.

Currently I have the following code, to produce the "tuple" list from the "row" KeyedTuple (using the intermediary "dictRow" dict, and the _asdict function for KeyedTuple), by excluding "month" and "year" fields:

```
values = []
dictRow = row._asdict()
for key in row.keys():
    if key not in ("year", "month"):
        print key, type(row), dictRow[key]
        values.append (dictRow[key])
```

Just in case it would be important, the context is having the result of a query for which I really need to exclude some fields, and obtain as a result the rest of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Better* is very subjective. But if you really want a `KeyedTuple` as well as preserve original order of values, below should work:

```
values = KeyedTuple(*zip(*(
                    (row[i], k) for i, k in enumerate(row.keys())
                    if not k in ("year", "month")
                    )))

# or, just simple tuple:
values = tuple(row[i] for i, k in enumerate(row.keys())
               if not k in ("year", "month"))
```

Why don't you just exclude those columns from the original query anyways?

Comment: Well, I can't exclude the columns from the query because includes a group_by. I need those fields in select of the query to have the periods (year and month) for each of the values (the rest of the fields in the query). But I'm sorting the information in a way where I only need the values, once I know the period.